# Chain method implementation with List of Linked Lists

Tags: java

I'm trying to implement chain method in Java. The table is of type `List<LinkedList<Entry<K, V>>>` and I need to add an entry to the right place. Lets say that the table is not empty and contains already some entries with specific key and value. The table itself is set up with following method:

```
public void setup(int size, HashFunction hashFunction, IntConverter<K> converter) {
        this.size = size;
        this.hashFunction = hashFunction;
        this.converter = converter;
        table = new ArrayList<>(size);

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            table.add(i, new LinkedList<Entry<K, V>>());
        }

    }
```

I will appreciate any help.

Comment: So what do you actually need? Or rather, what have you tried? All you show us is your set up code, what have you tried for your chained add method?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
public void chainMethod(int desiredIndex, LinkedList<> list) {
    for (int i = 0; desiredIndex <= table.size() - i; i++) {
        if (i == 0)
            table.add(table.get(table.size());
        else if (desiredIndex == table.size() - i)
            table.set(desiredIndex, list);
        else
            table.set(table.size() - i, table.get(table.size() - (i + 1)));
    }
}
```

This is pretty much psuedocode, I'm on my phone